# Why is this an infinite loop?

Tags: loops

```
while userinput != "yard" or userinput != "gym" or userinput != "basement" or userinput != "cell" or userinput != "showers" or userinput != "outside":
            print "Enter 'yard' or 'gym' or 'basement' or 'cell' or 'showers' or 'outside' to search them."
            if userinput == "yard":
                Rooms.yard()
            elif userinput == "gym":
                Rooms.gym()
            elif userinput == "basement":
                Rooms.basement()
            elif userinput == "cell":
                Rooms.cell()
            elif userinput == "showers":
                Rooms.showers()
            elif userinput == "outside":
                Rooms.outside()
            else:
                end_game()
```

It doesn't go into an infinite loop when I enter the prompts listed but once I hit enter it goes into an infinite loop. Why is that? I tried to figure out why but I'm having a hard time. Thanks

Comment: `"yard" != "gym"` so `userinput != "yard" or userinput != "gym" or ...` is always True. ​ ​

Comment: I don't think "please debug my code" is on-topic anywhere on the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is:

```
while userinput != "yard" or userinput != "gym" or ...
```

By using De Morgan's law it is equivalent to:

```
while !(userinput == "yard" and userinput == "gym" and ...)
```

As `userinput` can only have a single value it cannot be equal to both "yard" and "gym" meaning that the expression in the brackets is always False making the whole condition !False = True no matter the value of the userinput.

I am unsure of what `end_game()` does so I cannot comment if it can break out of the loop or not.